# If $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $Z_m$ to $Z_n$, and $gcd(n,m)=d$, then $|Im\phi|$ divides $d$

Tags: group-theory

I am stuck on this simple step in a proof... I know that the imagine is a subgroup of the codomain, but what does this have to do with the gcd?

Comment: $|Im\phi|$ must be a divisor of the orders of both the domain (by the first isomorphism theorem) and the codomain (because the image is a subgroup of the codomain). Therefore...?

Comment: It is a divisor but how do I know its the greatest one?

Comment: The claim is not that $|Im \phi|$ is the gcd. But it's a divisor of $n$ and $m$, so it must also be a divisor of their gcd. That's what is meant by **greatest** common divisor.

Answer (score 2):

$\phi:Z_m\rightarrow Z_n$ is a homomorphism, *i.e*,  $\phi:Z_m\rightarrow Im\phi$ is a epimorphism (surjective homomorphism).
From first isomorphism theorem we have, $Z_m/ker\phi\cong Im\phi$. Therefore, $m/|ker\phi|=|Im\phi|$ this gives $m=|Im\phi|.|ker\phi|$ so $|Im\phi|$ divides $m$. Now, $Im\phi$ being a subgroup of $Z_n$, $|Im\phi|$ divides $n$.
 Now $|Im\phi|$ divides both *m* and *n* , *d* being the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$ we conclude, $|Im\phi|$ divides $d$.